# Assigning correct value for datetime HTML pattern

Tags: php, html, mysql, datetime

I'm trying to convert and output the DATE of a notice from my MySQL DB to the HTML format.

```
<time datetime=$DATE> $DATE-FOR-HUMANS </time>
```

So, it will vary from notice to notice.

SELECTING NOTICE:

```
"select id,title,date_format(date, '%a %b %d, %Y %h:%i') as date from NOTICES";
```

VARIABLES:

```
$id = $arr['id'];
$date = $arr['date'];
```

Date will look like this:

```
Mon Jan 01, 2012 - 01:01
```

I noticed that the correct value for "date datetime" should be like this:

```
Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z
```

So, i must change the outputs.
One must be easier for humans to read (Mon Jan 01, 2012 - 01:01) and the other for the HTML pattern.

My question is: how to convert that "$DATE" variable on to the acceptable format and keep/make another for humans to read.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you changed your query to:

```
select id,title,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) as timestamp from NOTICES
```

Then you can pass `$arr['timestamp']` to PHP's [`date`](http://php.net/date) function and format it any number of ways very easily since you have a timestamp representation of the date.

Comment: Honestly I don't get it...but I'll try to see what happens...
I don't know how to use the PHP "date" function.

Comment: I did this and seems to be working fine ... "select id, title, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) as timestamp, date_format(date, '%a %b %d, %Y %h:%i') as formatted_date from NOTICES";

Comment: Click the link to date and you can read about how to use it.  I'm sure it will be useful at some point.  That way you aren't stuck with one hard to use date format coming out of the database.  Timestamps are flexible and easy to turn into any format you want.

Comment: Oh, that was a link ... I didn't saw the first time. It's nice, seems to be exactly what I was looking for... Before come and ask here I googled: "format_date php" and was directed on to the wrong way, but now it seems a good way. Thanks again

Comment: Thank you, I could use the built in "DATE" function successfully.

Comment: I had only a curious issue with this function. I hope you can explain me. When getting and formatting date directly from the mysql SELECT, I got this date: "13th September", but getting it as "UNIX_TIMESTAMP" and then formatting propperly it was changed to: "12th September". Why?

Comment: Sounds like the timezone setting in MySQL and PHP are probably set to different values.

Comment: PHP has a default timezone based on date.timezone in php.ini, MySQL also has a timezone generally based on the server timezone.  It also depends on what timezones your dates are in when you put them in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Let your query result both date formats.

```
"select id, title, date, date_format(date, '%a %b %d, %Y %h:%i') as formatted_date from NOTICES";
```

Comment: I made this and it seems to work fine..."select id, title, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) as timestamp, date_format(date, '%a %b %d, %Y %h:%i') as formatted_date from NOTICES";